# How do I print the elements in a list in a loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to understand how for loops work. I create a list which looks like below:

```
> ldf 

[[1]] [1] "David_T2.png"

[[2]] [1] "David_T3.png"

[[3]] [1] "COLOn_T2.png"

[[4]] [1] "COLOn_T4.png"
```

and create a loop like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(ldf)){
 for (j in 2:length(ldf)){
 print(ldf[[i]])
 print(ldf[[j]])
} 
}
```

But I don't get the expected result I would like that it prints the first, then the second, then the thirds file and so on; instead, I obtain this:

```
[1] "David_T2.png"
[1] "David_T3.png"
[1] "David_T2.png"
[1] "COLOn_T2.png"
[1] "David_T2.png"
[1] "COLOn_T4.png"
[1] "David_T2.png"
```

And I can't understand why.

Comment: Because it is printing the first print statement first, then the second one in each loop

Comment: Print out i and j in the loop to see what's happening; `message(i,",",j)` will do that nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You only need a single loop to iterate over the elements. Having a second, nested loop causes your innermost statements to be executed for each *pair* of elements in the list, rather than for each element once.

Furthermore, there’s no need to iterate over indices; you can iterate over the list items directly:

```
for (item in ldf) {
    message(item)
}
```

Note that I’ve used `message` instead of `print` here, as this is more suitable.

However, this can also be written without a loop, by using [`lapply`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.0/topics/lapply): `lapply` is a function that takes *another function* (here, `print`), and just calls it on every element:

```
lapply(ldf, message)
```

Comment: Or even just `ldf` :-P

Comment: @Hugh Ah, I’ve changed my answer so that they’re no longer equivalent. Using `print` here was inappropriate anyway.

Comment: @Hugh *I'm trying to understand how for loops works* That's the question. But you don't need loops in r that frequently.